# Closest position between randomly moving objects

Tags: sql, math

I have a large database tables that contains grid references (X and Y) associated with various objects (each with a unique object identifier) as they move with time. The objects move at approximately constant speed but random directions.

The table looks something like this….

```
CREATE TABLE positions (
  objectId              INTEGER,
  x_coord              INTEGER,
  y_coord              INTEGER,
  posTime             TIMESTAMP);
```

I want to find which two objects got closest to each other and at what time.

Finding the distance between two fixes is relatively easy – simple Pythagoras for the differences between the X and Y values should do the trick.

The first problem seems to be one of volume. The grid itself is large, 100,000 possible X co-ordinates and a similar number of Y co-ordinates. For any given time period the table might contain 10,000 grid reference positions for 1000 different objects – 10 million rows in total.
That’s not in itself a large number, but I can’t think of a way of avoiding doing a ‘product query’ to compare every fix to every other fix. Doing this with 10 million rows will produce 100 million million results.
The next issue is that I’m not just interested in the closest two fixes to each other, I’m interested in the closest two fixes from *different* objects.
Another issue is that I need to match time as well as position – I’m not just interested in two objects that have visited the same grid square, they need to have done so at the *same* time.

The other point (may not be relevant) is that the items are unlikely to every occupy exactly the same location at the same time.

I’ve got as far as a simple product query with a few sample rows, but I’m not sure on my next steps. I’m beginning to think this isn’t going something I can pull off with a single SQL query (please prove me wrong) and I’m likely to have to extract the data and subject it to some procedural programming.

Any suggestions?

I’m not sure what SE forum this best suited for – database SQL? Programming? Maths?

UPDATE - Another issue to add to the complexity, the timestamping for each object and position is irregular, one item might have a position recorded at 14:10:00 and another at 14:10:01. If these two positions are right next to each other and one second apart then they may actually represent the closest position although the time don't match!

Comment: This is a different one.

Answer (score 0):

In order to reduce the number of tested combinations you should segregate them by `postime` using subqueries. Also, it's recommended you create an index by `postime` to increase performance.

```
create index ix1_time on positions (postime);
```

Since you didn't mention any specific database I assumed PostgreSQL since it's easy to use (for me). The solution should look like:

```
with t as (
  select distinct(postime) as pt from positions
)
select *
  from t,
  (
  select * 
    from (
      select
        a.objectid as aid, b.objectid as bid,
        a.x_coord + a.y_coord + b.x_coord + b.y_coord as dist -- fix here!
      from t
      join positions a on a.postime = t.pt
      join positions b on b.postime = t.pt
      where a.objectid <> b.objectid
      ) x
    order by dist desc
    limit 1
  ) y;
```

This SQL should compare each 10000 objects against each other on by postime. It will test 10 million combinations for each different postime value, but not against other postime values.

**Please note:** I used `a.x_coord + a.y_coord + b.x_coord + b.y_coord` as the distance formula. I leave the correct one for you to implement here.

In total it will compute 10 million x 1000 time values: a total of 10 billion comparisons. It will return the closest two points for each timepos, that is a total of 1000 rows.